# Yocto menuconfig not working

Tags: linux, embedded-linux, yocto, bitbake, openembedded

For some reason the menuconfig menu does not come up when I try launching it from my Yocto installation. I am using the Toradex Yocto 1.6 system as is described here http://developer.toradex.com/software-resources/arm-family/linux/board-support-package/openembedded-%28core%29, with my board set to "apalis-t30". When I run either bitbake virtual/kernal -c menuconfig or bitbake linux-toradex -c menuconfig, it executes fine but finishes (without erros) before actually showing anything. Running devshell also gives the same results.

If I just use the kernel sources on their own as is described here http://developer.toradex.com/software-resources/arm-family/linux/board-support-package/build-u-boot-and-linux-kernel-from-source-code, I can get menuconfig open using make nconfig. From the Yocto scripts it appears as if though the exact same kernel sources are being used. If I try adding adding make nconfig to the do_configure_prepend script in the linux-toradex_git.bb file then the commands get stuck stating that the process (I assume menuconfig) is running and then provides a PID for it, but no window or menu is displayed anywhere and the task does not seem to finish.

PS. I am on Fedora 21 64-bit.

EDIT:
I have now checked the default Yocto image and menuconfig comes up fine there. I am assuming that the Toradex BSP is not entirely compatible enough with Yocto for this to work out of the box. I have spoken to Toradex and they have told me that I should instead fork their kernel, modify it the normal way in my own repo and then tell the script to pull from my modified repo. I guess this could work but its a bit of a hassle and I would like to fix their Yocto system. I am assuming that this cannot be to hard as running make nconfig is usually enough, I just can't figure out how to get that command working with bitbake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work fine with the meta-toradex layer.  In the local.conf file, comment out the INHERIT += "rm_work" line:

```
#INHERIT += "rm_work"
```

Then do a full build of the kernel:

```
MACHINE=apalis-t30 bitbake virtual/kernel
```

Then try menuconfig now that all the sources are in place:

```
MACHINE=apalis-t30 bitbake -c menuconfig virtual/kernel
```

Comment: It still goes through do_menuconfig without flinching. Have you tested that you can get it working using their files?

Comment: Yes, bitbake -c menuconfig with the apalis-t30 kernel is working fine on my system.  Which repo branch are you sync'd to?  Which version of ncurses-devel do you have installed? Do you ever see a new console window open (and immediately close)?

Comment: I believe that I am on the "V2.3" repo branch. According to Yum I have "ncurses-devel-5.9-16.20140323.fc21.x86_64" which it believes is the latest version. I do recall that a new window came up and immediately closed in one of my attempts but it is not happening at the moment.

Comment: It appears that this could be the issue you are experiencing:  [link](http://patchwork.openembedded.org/patch/45493/).  Perhaps applying this patch to your _openembedded-core/meta/classes/cml1.bbclass_ would do the trick - or - perhaps the file could simply be copied from the latest default Yocto image that you set up.  You could also try installing ncurses-devel.i686 on your host.

Comment: I have tried both those things to no effect on a completely standard repo. On what Linux distro are you?

Comment: I'm using Linux Mint 17.1 x64.

Comment: I'll try testing with that Linux, hopefully it solves my problem

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Ubuntu, try to reconfigure system shell to bash instead of dash(that is default for Ubuntu):

> $ sudo dpkg-reconfigure dash

press "No" when prompted.

Actually I got the same problem few times. In one case shell reconfigure helped me.

Comment: I can second that this solution is not all that helpful. I appreciate your effort, but it really does not solve the issue on a consistent basis.